# Define a variable in a try block in C#

Tags: c#

I don't want to have ultra-deep nested blocks, so in cases that variable initialisation could error I would prefer to do it like this:

```cs
try
{
    var foo = GetFoo();
}
catch (FooException)
{
   Console.Write(...);
   throw;
}

var bar = GetBar(foo);
```

Of course it doesn't compile. I'm not allowed to use `foo` outside of the try-block that initialises it.

Putting a full type specification right above the block also sucks in my opinion:

```cs
FooType foo;
try
{
    foo = GetFoo();
}
catch (FooException)
{
   Console.Write(...);
   throw;
}

var bar = GetBar(foo);
```

Even in less extreme cases, like just `int foo = 0;`, it already feels dirty, especially with that confusing unused initial value. The `catch` block exits the program anyway.

How can I try-initialise a variable and use it outside of that scope, with minimal repetition and minimal characters typed?

---

Why I think I dislike the lifted variable declaration solution:

I prefer to avoid typed variable declarations. I dislike repetition. I dislike the disconnect between declaration of the variable and its initialisation. I dislike setting unused initial values. The last two points probably come from a subconscious association with violation of immutability; I tend to like as many variables as possible being conceptually `readonly` and having separate declaration and initialisation contradicts that pattern.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238115/discussion-on-question-by-theonlygusti-define-variable-in-try-block-c).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be putting the initialization logic into another method and wrap it with `try`/`catch` there, so then you can have:

```
var foo = InitializeFoo();
var bar = GetBar(foo);

private Foo InitializeFoo() 
{
     try {
         // initalize and return foo
     }
     catch {
        throw;
     }
}
```

You can generalize this by passing a `delegate` to the `Initialize` method that specifies the initiaze logic and use it for anything else.

```
public T InitializeVariable<T>(Func<T> initializeAction)
{
     try {
         var x = initializeAction();
         return x;
     }
     catch {
        throw;
     }
}
```

Comment: The initialiser is also the one that should decide what happens on an error. I was just writing `throw;` but of course the caller of `InitializeFoo` would also be the one who wants to specify error behaviour

Comment: @minseong so do you mean the exception type that must be catched can also change?

Comment: For example `catch (...Exception) { // do some cleanup, debug logging`, all subject to the caller's will.

Comment: @minseong That can also be generalized by using a callback delegate for error handling.

Comment: Why do you think this kind of `TryInitialize(initializer, onError)` method isn't in the language?

Comment: The second snippet: How is that different form calling the initializeAction directly?

Comment: @Fildor the try/catch block is outsourced, so the caller won't end up with a variable that only exists in some inner scope.

Comment: I don't see the usecase unless you also pass errorhandling code.

Comment: @Fildor I didn't either, and that's what the first comments here are about....

Comment: @minseong it's indeed useless without error handling, but it's trivial to add it there by passing another delegate. Then will you be satisfied with such solution?